# Mathematcia Import data text, how to implement 3D interpolation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-interpolation

There is a data of 4*531441, the first column is k1, the second column is k2, the third column is k3, and the fourth column is B(k1, k2, k3). How does mathematica do the interpolation function B(k1,k2,k3)?

```
In[105]:= 
data1 = Import[
   "/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=202.197.126.00,user=wupu/home/\
wupu/ouhe0035-da/401/bb.log"];


In[106]:= 
pts = Table[{data1[[i, 1]], data1[[i, 2]], data1[[i, 3]], 
    data1[[i, 4]]}, {i, 4, Length[data1]}];

In[90]:= Table1[[1]]

Out[90]= {5.7983*10^17, 5.7983*10^17, 6.2499*10^17, -9.36702*10^-108}

In[108]:= 
B[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, #[[4]]} \
& /@ pts, {x, y, z}]]

\:6B63\:5728\:8BA1\:7B97In[108]:= General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

\:6B63\:5728\:8BA1\:7B97In[108]:= Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].

Out[108]= SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
```

Comment: The data text looks like{1,1,1,100},{1,1,2,112},{1,1,3,115},{1,2,1,200},{1,2,2,300},{1,2,3,400},{1,3,1,200},{1,3,2,344},{1,3,3,300},{2,1,1,300}.....

Comment: If I carefully read the help pages it describes how to format the data for multivariable interpolation. `data={{{1,1,1},100},{{1,1,2},112},{{1,1,3},115},{{1,2,1},200},{{1,2,2},300},{{1,2,3},400},{{1,3,1},200},{{1,3,2},344},{{1,3,3},300},{{2,1,1},300}};f=Interpolation[data];
f[1,1,1.5]` gives a warning about your numbers not having decimal points and it treats those as if they did. Then it does an interpolation. If I instead try `g=InterpolatingPolynomial[data,{x,y,z}];g[1,1,1.5]` gives an error https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/InterpolatingPolynomial/poised.html Helps?